# Why index is displayed when trying to install phpmyadmin?

Tags: macos, apache, phpmyadmin, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install `phpmyadmin` on OSX 10.9.2 based on the instructions [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/installing-phpmyadmin-on-mac-osx-10-7-lion/).

The problem is, when I visit `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup` I see the index rather than the installation screen:

[image]

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: It sounds like you don't have PHP installed, or Apache is not configured to call PHP for `.php` files. Does it work if you go to `setup/index.php`? If so, then `index.php` is not listed as an index file (er, or whatever that's called).

Comment: Looks like your webserver is not configured to run PHP and/or is not configured to return `index.php` if a directory is accessed. What happens if you try to load the file?

Comment: When I visit "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php", I see the contents of `index.php`: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1893981/Screenshots/y8vg.png

Comment: Then, like I said, you either don't have PHP installed, or Apache is not configured correctly to use PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to uncomment the following line in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to solve the issue:

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```